# PCA and Later RegressionAnalusis

Tags: regression, pca

I ran a PCA using Stata 15. Results from both the Kaiser Scree Plot and parallel analysis suggested a two component solution. The scores for PC-1 and PC-2 were predicted in Stata; both have a mean of 0 and SD equal to the variance of the related eigenvalues. 
I want to use both PC-1 and PC-2 in a regression analysis. Do I need to z-score the component scores for interpretability or does that matter? 
Also, I have one large analytic sample of 18,000+ students. I have also broken them down into racial/ethnic subgroups - White, African American, Hispanic and Asian.
Do I need to run a separate PCA for each of the subgroups? Many thanks, Pat